# Can I use VisualStudio 2010 for SharePoint 2013 development?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I have some limitation in using development environment of Sharepoint.

We have Visual Studio 2010 installed on Sharepoint foundation server machine.
But we are not able to create webpart as VS2010 is showing only 2007 and 2010 templates. However when we select 2010 template it says Sharepoint is not installed. 
Is there any plugins or Patch is available so that it works somehow.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: did u get the solution for the same? As I am having the similar requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short answer: **NO** SharePoint 2013 is supported with VS 2012 / 2013 /2015 /2017.

Regarding `"when we select 2010 template it says Sharepoint is not installed."`

I think it's a normal behavior because you already have SharePoint 2013, not SharePoint 2010 and when you try to create a solution with SharePoint 2010 template that means you should have SharePoint 2010 installed that it is actually not installed!

Comment: any Patch or plugin can be install? so that I can create webpart for SP2013 in VS2010?

Comment: unfortunately no you should install visual studio 2012 as a minimum but i suggest to install VS 2015 with Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 to avoid missing SharePoint template as mentioned at https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/